# why my method from protocol delegate pattern triggered automatically when updating stepper inside collection view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, realm, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to make an app that can save a product to a cart (order) using collection view, there is a stepper inside each collection view cell.

here is the project file in the google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ax7VLpI8Vb2jFSJxn_Ss_TjEECbDt-fs/view?usp=sharing

and here is the screenshot of the app (please ignore the ugly UI):
[image]

there are 6 products displayed in the collection view cell. each collection view cell has name label, add to cart button and a stepper.

add to cart button and the stepper has the same size and located at the same place, once the add to cart button is tapped, then it will hide the add to cart button and it will show up the stepper like the gif in here:
http://g.recordit.co/DAKMvFwQs4.gif

I use the code below for my Collection view cell, I pass the data using protocol and delegate pattern :

```
protocol OrderCellDelegate {
    func addToCartButtonDidTapped(at selectedIndexPath: IndexPath)
    func stepperDidTapped(at selectedIndexPath:IndexPath, counterValue: Int)
}


class OrderCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepper: GMStepper!
    @IBOutlet var addToCartButton: UIButton!


    var productData : Product? {
        didSet {
            setStepper()
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    var indexPath: IndexPath?
    var delegate: OrderCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func AddToCartButtonDidTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let selectedIndexPath = indexPath else {return}
        self.delegate?.addToCartButtonDidTapped(at: selectedIndexPath)
    }


    @IBAction func stepperButtonDidTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let selectedIndexPath = indexPath else {return}
        let value = Int(stepper.value)
        self.delegate?.stepperDidTapped(at: selectedIndexPath, counterValue: value)
    }

    func setStepper() {
        guard let product = productData else {return}
        stepper.value = Double(product.quantityInCart)
        stepper.autorepeat = false
        stepper.minimumValue = 0
        stepper.maximumValue = 100
        stepper.stepValue = 1.0

    }

    func updateUI() {
        guard let product = productData else {return}
        nameLabel.text = product.name
        setCartAndStepperButton()
    }

    private func setCartAndStepperButton() {

        guard let selectedProduct = productData else {return}

        func showStepperButton(status: Bool) {
            // to decide whether to show stepper or add to cart button.
            stepper.isHidden = !status
            stepper.isEnabled = status

            addToCartButton.isHidden = status
            addToCartButton.isEnabled = !status

        }

        if selectedProduct.quantityInCart == 0 {
            showStepperButton(status: false)
        } else {
            showStepperButton(status: true)
            stepper.value = Double(selectedProduct.quantityInCart)
        }


    }


}
```

and here is the code for my view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, OrderCellDelegate  {


    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var order : Order!
    var allProducts = [Product]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        order = Order.getOrderFromRealmDatabase()
        allProducts = Product.fetchProductData()

    }


    func addToCartButtonDidTapped(at selectedIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("A")
        let selectedProduct = allProducts[selectedIndexPath.item]
        Order.addProductToOrderRealmDatabase(userOrder: order, selectedProduct: selectedProduct)
        collectionView.reloadData()

    }

    func stepperDidTapped(at selectedIndexPath: IndexPath, counterValue: Int) {

        print("B")


    }


}


// DATA SOURCE
extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allProducts.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "orderCell", for: indexPath) as! OrderCell

        cell.productData = allProducts[indexPath.item]
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.indexPath = indexPath

        return cell
    }

}
```

and the problem is .....

when I tap the add to cart button, it will trigger `addToCartButtonDidTapped` on my view controller. but... I don't understand why when I tap the add to cart button, it will also trigger the `stepperDidTapped` method

so when `addToCartButtonDidTapped` , it will automatically triggered `stepperDidTapped` method. print("A") and print("B") are triggered at the same time.

as you can see the `stepperDidTapped` method should only triggred when I tap the stepper not the add to cart button, I use 2 differents method on `OrderCellDelegate`

I don't understand why. Do I have a wrong way to implement stepper inside the collection view cell like that ? to be honest, I am not sure with my code to implement stepper inside the collection view above.

here is the file of the project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ax7VLpI8Vb2jFSJxn_Ss_TjEECbDt-fs/view?usp=sharing

here is the Product model:

```
import RealmSwift


class Product : Object {

    @objc dynamic var productID : Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var unitPrice: Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var quantityInCart : Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var descriptionProduct : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var hasBeenAddedToCart : Bool = false


    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "productID"
    }

    convenience init(productID: Int, name: String, unitPrice: Double, descriptionProduct: String) {
        self.init()


        self.productID = productID
        self.name = name
        self.unitPrice = unitPrice
        self.descriptionProduct = descriptionProduct

    }

    static func fetchProductData() -> [Product] {

        let product1 = Product(productID: 1, name: "Product1", unitPrice: 1000, descriptionProduct: "Description of Product 1")
        let product2 = Product(productID: 2, name: "Product2", unitPrice: 2000, descriptionProduct: "Description of Product 2")
        let product3 = Product(productID: 3, name: "Product3", unitPrice: 3000, descriptionProduct: "Description of Product 3")
        let product4 = Product(productID: 4, name: "Product4", unitPrice: 4000, descriptionProduct: "Description of Product 4")
        let product5 = Product(productID: 5, name: "Product5", unitPrice: 5000, descriptionProduct: "Description of Product 5")
        let product6 = Product(productID: 6, name: "Product6", unitPrice: 6000, descriptionProduct: "Description of Product 6")

        return [product1,product2,product3,product4,product5,product6]
    }


    static func changeProductQuantityInRealmDatabase(selectedProduct: Product, quantity: Int) {

        guard let selectedProductInRealmDatabase = RealmService.shared.realm.objects(Product.self).filter("productID == %@", selectedProduct.productID).first else {return}

        RealmService.shared.updateOnCertainKey(object: selectedProductInRealmDatabase, for: ["quantityInCart": quantity])

    }



}
```

and here is the Order model:

```
import RealmSwift


class Order : Object {
    @objc dynamic var userID: String = ""
    var products = List<Product>()


    convenience init (userID: String, products: List<Product>) {
        self.init()
        self.userID = "1"
        self.products = products
    }

    //MARK: - Realm Related

    static func getOrderFromRealmDatabase() -> Order {

        let userID = "1"
        let realmService = RealmService.shared.realm
        let allOrder = realmService.objects(Order.self)
        let theOrder = allOrder.filter("userID CONTAINS[cd] %@", userID).first

        if let userOrder = theOrder {
            return userOrder
        } else {
            // Order never setted up before in Realm database container
            // then create Order in realm database

            let newOrder = Order()
            newOrder.userID = userID
            newOrder.products = List<Product>()
            RealmService.shared.save(object: newOrder)
            return newOrder

        }

    }

    static func addProductToOrderRealmDatabase(userOrder: Order, selectedProduct: Product) {

        // to check wheter the selected product from user is already in Order or not

        if userOrder.products.filter("productID == %@", selectedProduct.productID).first == nil {

            // check if the selected product has already available in Product.self database or not
            if let matchingProduct = RealmService.shared.realm.objects(Product.self).filter("productID == %@", selectedProduct.productID).first {

                RealmService.shared.save(expression: {
                    userOrder.products.append(matchingProduct)
                    matchingProduct.hasBeenAddedToCart = true
                    matchingProduct.quantityInCart = 1
                })


            } else {

                RealmService.shared.save(expression: {
                    userOrder.products.append(selectedProduct)
                    selectedProduct.hasBeenAddedToCart = true
                    selectedProduct.quantityInCart = 1
                })

            }

        }

    }




}
```

Comment: Thats a weird behaviour. Does it still do it when you set userInteraction as well as isEnabled at the buttons?

Comment: Did you connect your `stepperButtonDidTapped()` func as an `IBAction` for the `Value Changed` event? If so, it is probably being triggered by how you set the value in your `cellForItemAt` function (since you are reloading the collection view).

Comment: Ah - just looked further at your code... you are executing `stepper.value = Double(selectedProduct.quantityInCart)` when you "show" your stepper... which will trigger `Value Changed`.